# How can I render an image with Padrino?

Tags: ruby, rmagick, padrino

I need to create image files on-the-fly in my controller with RMagick and send them to browser. Looks like it's very simple, but I can't find a way. I've tried just simply `render` them, but it fails due to data is binary. I've also tried to use `send_data`, but Padrino says it doesn't know about such method.

So, what have I missed? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to sinatra api you don't need this anymore.

```
get :image, with: id, provides: :png do
  img = Image.find(params[:id])
  img.binary_data_or_so
end
```

basically is the same of:

```
get '/send_binarydata' do
  content_type 'image/png'
  \x01\x02\x03
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Researching how to send files through Padrino controller I've found this question and it helps me to reach my goal.

The send_data method is a Sinatra request-method which has been removed in the version 1.0: https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/1.0/CHANGES#L108

I'm using the Padrino version 0.10.7 and my action have became into this:

```
get :screenshot, :provides => :jpg do
  ...
  File.open("path/to/file", "r").readlines
end
```